Program runs correctly when using debugger but fails when execute it directly
I'm currently facing a problem that when i'm using x32dbg to debug my MASM program it worked smoothly like I wanted without any error. But when I run the program directly without debugging it somehow went wrong and I don't know why.
I have tried to debug it over and over, and yet no error were found while tracing through x32Dbg. This is the first time I've met this kind of problem, can someone explain it to me?
The entire program is a bit long so I have posted the link to my github repo so that you guys can review it easily. I'm still in the process of learning in this field so any help or suggestion will be very much appreciated
This is the program

I am sure many people would like to explain it. But we need to see the actual code that you are trying to debug, in order to help.

I have added the link to my source code, sir.

My version pf Microsoft's masm cannot compile that source. Which version are you using. You also need to explain what the code is suppposed to do.

I'm trying to make the program that will inject the code to other exe files in the current directory. This is supposed to be a shellcode so that't why i don't use any external but load libraries and API manually.

But at the moment, I'm just trying to change the visual size of all the exe files, but it  seems like it got weird crash when running without debugging.

I have fixed it. For some reason that after calling an API function, the value that stored in edx will change but when using x32Dbg it didn't. Maybe this is a bug.

The github link in your question gives me error 404. BTW, with this kind of problems, I would intuitively suspect something like a stray pointer, respectively an unititialized pieces of storage. Also (for the safe side), it could help to document, how you assemble and run it with, and without debugger.
